# Azure Analysis Services identity error when deploying

Tags: azure-analysis-services

We've developed a tabular model over the past few months using an on-premise Analysis Services instance. We now wish to deploy this model to an AAS instance.

I changed the server property to point to the AAS instance. (I've had success deploying a test model.) When I deploy, I encounter an "error deploying metadata."

The odd thing about this error message is that it contains a credential that is not mine. It belongs to a colleague, and I've never used it.

Here's the error:
Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'The identity 'domain\credentialthatisnotmine' has invalid identity provider ''. Only Azure Active Directory users or groups are supported. Use 'AzureAD' as the value of the identity provider.

Technical Details:

RootActivityId: d6691bc1-6c30-4cf7-9bf0-03b7bf7ed258
Date (UTC): 7/27/2018 4:45:13 PM
'.

I can't find that credential anywhere in the project.

Any assistance welcome of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is still valid. I believe you need to add a new db role to the AAS instance. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-database-users

The db role needs RBAC which i did through the portal at a resource group level. Hopefully this makes sense.